# Reading Specific Row from CSV using CSV Data Set Config Element in JMeter Based on Column Value

Tags: jmeter

I have two CSV files, one containing a set of parent objects, and another child objects. I would like for my JMeter script to iterate through the set of parent objects, send requests for these objects and then iterate through the set of child objects.

The problem is, that for each parent object, there exists a sub-set of children which belong to the set of child objects. As such, when looping through the set of child objects, only certain records can be used for the parent.

Example:

Parent Set
{A, B, C, D, E}

Child Set
{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}

Constraints:
1 and 2 are children of A, 2 and 3 are children of B, 3 is a child of C, 4 is a child of D and 5 is a child of E.

Thus, when processing parent A, only the children 1 and 2 can be considered. When processing parent E, only the child, 5 can be considered.

These constraints are supplied in the child CSV.

How can this be implemented in JMeter?

I have a few ideas on how to implement this, however am unsure if they are any good:

- Create a CSV for each sub-set of children.
- When reading from the set of children after creating a parent object, continue to iterate through the CSV until a suitable child is found, then proceed.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Given "These constraints are supplied in the child CSV." a single "child CSV" should be sufficient.

Without seeing at least partial contents of the CSV files it is impossible to come up with the most elegant solution. Few more ideas:

1. You can pre-process the data and generate a "cumulative" CSV file somewhere in [setUp Thread Group](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/thread-group-jmeter) using [JSR223 Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler)
2. There is [__CSVRead()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__CSVRead) function where you can specify where to proceed to the next line, it also supports dynamic CSV file inputs
3. With __groovy() function you can parse any CSV file in any flexible way, see [Reading and Writing CSV files with Groovy](https://groovy.apache.org/blog/reading-and-writing-csv-files) article for more information.